# A lot of critical warning appear when launching Chrome from terminal

Tags: command-line, drivers, google-chrome

I've found myself running Chrome from the terminal after reinstalling it, and there are a lot of errors in the terminal. I don't know if there were there before the reinstalling since it's the first time I run Chrome from terminal.

The weird thing is Chrome works and I can use it normally tho (apart from a problem I had which was the reason for the reinstall)

Almost all of them mention "driver" and "critical" so, although Chrome works, I think it's something I should fix.

- Ubuntu 22.04
- CPU i5-5600
- GPU 1060 6GB
- Dual booting, not VM

Here (the white spaces at the end is because the terminal looks like it's waiting to print something):

```
[41244:41244:0613/005814.971735:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41244:41244:0613/005814.971936:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41244:41244:0613/005814.972094:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[41244:41244:0613/005814.975504:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41244:41244:0613/005814.975705:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41244:41244:0613/005814.975842:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[41244:41244:0613/005814.975942:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(21)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[41244:41244:0613/005814.977553:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[41276:41276:0613/005815.186365:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41276:41276:0613/005815.186480:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41276:41276:0613/005815.186538:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[41276:41276:0613/005815.189838:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41276:41276:0613/005815.189948:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41276:41276:0613/005815.189984:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[41276:41276:0613/005815.190015:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(21)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[41276:41276:0613/005815.191473:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[41333:41333:0613/005815.441554:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41333:41333:0613/005815.441680:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41333:41333:0613/005815.441727:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[41333:41333:0613/005815.449443:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:977 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41333:41333:0613/005815.449528:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(852)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[41333:41333:0613/005815.449568:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1489)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[41333:41333:0613/005815.449606:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(21)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[41333:41333:0613/005815.459117:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[41396:41396:0613/005815.529938:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[41309:8:0613/005815.543570:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(126)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[41201:41201:0613/005816.577362:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[41201:41201:0613/005816.578347:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Object does not exist at path “/”
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
```

Comment: @Nmath I'm sorry, I fixed it. And I launched it from the terminal just because I just installed it and didn't want to go to the icon, nothing special to be honest

Comment: Do you have Nvidia drivers installed? And Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: Looks like mainly errors related to graphics acceleration, so probably related also to the graphics card you use (e.g. Nvidia indeed). I have only two errors formatted this way,  and then a series of errors with different layout that include `skiashader compilation error`.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes

Comment: @vanadium then there's no way to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps, I don't know.